# ASP.NET Sql Provider

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008, dbconnection

I got a problem. When i'm creating the new project in ASP.NET using VS 2010, it's web.config with a default connection string about SQL Express created. But i haven't even got SQL Express installed. What should i do to change the default AspNetSqlProvider to work with my instance of full-weight SQL Server as a services database? And how can i change the template for the ASP.NET project to create a project with my connection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean this one:
`<add name="ApplicationServices"
         connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

To change this into one that'll work with SQL Server, it needs to look more like this:
`<add name="ApplicationServices"
         connectionString="data source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`
where DatabaseName is *probably* aspnetdb. It'll need some form of authentication, whether you use Windows authentication (in which case you can copy the `Integrated Security` element from the original connection string) or SQL Server authentication (where you'll have a username/password combination).
There's great info on building connection strings at [connectionstrings.com](http://connectionstrings.com).

To fix this for your future projects, you'll need to change the template for Web Projects. Locate the folder where your C# Web templates are kept (for me this is `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\CSharp\Web\1033`.
Take a copy of the WebApplicationProject40.zip file (you might also want to backup the original somewhere!). 
Inside it you'll find the web.config file with the SQL Express connection string. Change it to a SQL Server string, and then re-assemble the zip file.
The last step is to rebuild the VS template cache - from a command-line (VS Command Prompt probably works best), run `devenv /installvstemplates`. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241279(VS.80).aspx) for details.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for saving the time i would dig for this information over the internet.
It works perfectly.

Comment: connectionstrings.com is always REALLY useful !

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem. I had a web site created in VS 2008 and wanted to try web parts. Added some to a page, then started getting:

> SQLExpress database file auto-creation error:
>
> The connection string specifies a local Sql Server Express instance using a database >location within the applications App_Data directory.

I ran aspnet_regsql.exe (wizard, in .Net framework folder) to create the database and then I added a connection string to web.config:

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="aspnet_membership" connectionString="Data Source=localhost; Initial Catalog=aspnetdb; Integrated Security=SSPI;"/>
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Then I added this to web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <webParts>
      <personalization defaultProvider="SqlPersonalizationProvider">
        <providers>
          <add name="SqlPersonalizationProvider"
          type="System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.SqlPersonalizationProvider"
          connectionStringName="aspnet_membership"
          applicationName="/" />
        </providers>
        <authorization>
          <deny users="*" verbs="enterSharedScope" />
          <allow users="*" verbs="modifyState" />
        </authorization>
      </personalization>
    </webParts>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```